# MASAS in Type $II_{1}$ factor

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $N$ be a type $II_{1}$ factor. Does there exist a diffuse abelian sub algebra of $N$ which is not Maximal abelian?

Answer (score 4):

In general, a diffuse abelian subalgebra of $N$ may not be a masa of $N$. Choose a projection $p$ in $N$ with trace $1/2$. Take a masa $M$ in $pNp$. There exists a unitary operator $u$ in $N$ such that $u^*pu=p^{\perp}$. Then, $\{x+u^*xu:x\in M\}$ is diffuse and abelian but not maximal.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope the question is clear now.@ Rui

Comment: Please clarify me why $\lbrace x+u^{*}xu :x \in M \rbrace$ is diffuse abelian but not maximal.

Comment: Intuitively, we can write $N=pNp\otimes M_2(C)$. If $M$ is a masa in $pNp$, then for every $x$ in $M$, the set of elements \begin{pmatrix} x&0\\0&x\\ \end{pmatrix} form a diffuse abelian subalgebra $M\otimes I_2$ of $N$. It is diffuse, since every projection of this form in the subalgebra is not minimal. Note that $M\otimes I_2$ is a proper subalgebra of $M\oplus M$. Thus $M\otimes I_2$ is not maximal.